# Specifying arguments with spaces for running a python script

Tags: python, arguments, space

How to run a python with arguments that would contain spaces? I am using MacOS

For example,

```
>python testProgram.py argument 1 argument 2
```

where "argument 1" is a single argument?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> where "argument 1" is a single argument.

You've basically answered your *own* question there, `"argument 1"` is indeed a single argument.

In other words, you need to quote it, something like one of:

```
python testProgram.py "argument 1" 'argument 2'
```

This isn't actually a Python issue however, it depends on the shell that you're using to run the Python script.

For example, with `bash`, there are differences between the single and double quotes, the most important of which is probably the various expansions like `$HOME` - the single quoted variant does not do those expansions.

Comment: What if I have sth like: RAW_PATH="/Volumes/TOSHIBA EXT/../" and I want to use $RAW_PATH as argument? This does not work for me.

Comment: @thigi: you would use `"${RAW_PATH}"` - variables work just fine within double quotes.

Comment: Okay thank you! Sorry for not trying that, but I thought that would not work and hence I did not try it! Sorry for this inconvenience...

Answer (score 3):

Enclose your parameters that contains spaces with double quotes

```
> python testProgram.py "argument 1" "argument 2"
```

this will work under Windows and Linux so chances are it'll be ok under Mac OS too.

Answer (score 2):

Or using `subprocess` from within python itself:

```
subprocess.call(['python','testProgram.py','argument 1','argument 2'])
```

But the other answers are more likely to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>python testProgram.py "argument 1" "argument 2"
```