# Space in python variable passed as argument to subprocess

Tags: java, websphere, jython, wsadmin

I have a variable `toPath` (contains path like `C:/Program Files(x86)/bla`).
This variable I pass as agrument: `'[-operation update -contents ' + toPath + ']'`
But because I have a space in this variable I get IllegalArgumentException.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? And what does the code look like? We'll need more information than that to help you. Please edit your question.

Comment: `toPath` is a string. Right? If it is, the cause of error you are mentioning is incorrect. Can you tell me the output for `type(toPath)`?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri this is string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specifying arguments with spaces for running a python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894815/specifying-arguments-with-spaces-for-running-a-python-script)

Comment: I thin you are trying to execute this command over shell? And you are using `subprocess` module. Right? Try this: `subprocess.check_call(['-operation', 'update', '-contents', toPath])` and let me know whether it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but it looks like you are trying to do a typical newcomer mistake.

If you are trying to run a command that is build from multiple variables you can be vulnerable to injection attacks. To prevent this, use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module and hand in all parameters as a list. The module will take care of all the stuff to make it work with spaces as well.

For example `ls -l` should be run as:

```
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Your example caontains `[]` and might be rather different but without it would be:

```
subprocess.call(['-operation','update', '-contents', toPath])
```

Please note that there are other functions than `call()` (which returns the return code only) in the subprocess module.

Answer (score 2):

Pass argument in double quotes.

```
toPath = "\"C:/Program Files(x86)/bla\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
'[-operation update -contents "' + toPath + '"]'
```