# Parsing arguments as single line or using a specified delimiter in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, delimiter

I want to parse the command line arguments while attempting to call the program in the following manner:

```
python plot.py --w --Develop origin plot --+3.5
```

I have been using `sys.argv` to parse them using a `for` loop:

```
for arg in sys,argv:
    print(arg)
```

Output:

```
plot.py
--w
--Developoriginplot
--+3.5
```

But I wish to get the output as follows:

```
plot.py
w
Develop origin plot
+3.5
```

Is there a way to split the line by specifying the delimeter `--` ?

Comment: Can't have spaces in arguments, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894815/specifying-arguments-with-spaces-for-running-a-python-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`" ".join()` the args first, then split by `--`.

```
import sys

args = " ".join(sys.argv) # join by spaces
args = [a.strip() for a in args.split("--")] # split by --, remove any extra spaces
print(args)
print("\n".join(args))
```

Output:

```
$ python plot.py --w --Develop origin plot --+3.5
['plot.py', 'w', 'Develop origin plot', '+3.5']
plot.py
w
Develop origin plot
+3.5
```

Comment: @seam Thank you so much! I wish I could up vote this twice!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the [argparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

and here is a sample code of usage:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                const=sum, default=max,
                help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to my problem? Could you enlighten me?

Comment: you are trying to manage command line aguments to your application, right? and you are doing it manually; however the argparser is the one for this purpose, and if you read the documentation you will find the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Let me go through it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split() and replace() functions. split() takes delimiter as an argument and replace takes two arguments - first one is the character you would like to replace (in your case the white space) and the second one is what you would like to replace it with.

```
#Your string
s = "--w --Develop origin plot --+3.5"

d = s.replace(' ','').split('--')[1:] 
print(d)

>>['w', 'Developoriginplot', '+3.5']
```

Then you can reference your arguments by the indices of this list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, split method can be used to break it down at the de-limited but you will notice that I get my desired output "Develop orign plot" as "Desiredorigin plot"

Comment: Updated as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you Mick! But the thing is that I am parsing this from the argument line and the line is coming as a single string unless we add double quotes at beginning and end of the entire line. But had given a good work around for it.

Comment: No problem. I think i got your comment wrong and provided wrong solution anyway. Glad you got it to work.