# Is there a way to preserve the amount of spaces between words when reading the command-line input?

Tags: python, argparse, argv

In other words, is there a way to distinguish the input `Hello  World` and the input `Hello World` using `sys.argv` or other built-in methods like `argparse`?

Comment: The arguments are separated and passed into your program by your shell. Python only gets them as separate words: it is outside Python's control.

Comment: Assuming you're on a Unix-like system, your code won't even _see_ those spaces. The Shell processes those arguments then essentially passes them into your code as `["Hello", "World"]`. If care about whitespace you'll have to pass them as a single argument, e.g. `python foo.py "Hello World"` or `python foo.py Hello\ World`.

Comment: `"Hello       World"`

Comment: Related (possibly a duplicate): [Specifying arguments with spaces for running a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11894815/6045800)

Answer (score -1):

Word splitting is performed by the shell, long before the arguments are passed to the utility. The utility never gets to see the command line, only the arguments array.